# Android.Gms.Maps.Utils.Clustering refreshing markers

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

I' m using 'Android.Gms.Maps.Utils.Clustering' binding library for Xamarin android.

I have approximately 1000 items to show in the map with search feature. So every time user search objects, I should refresh markers in the Map, here is my code :

```
private void SetPointersOnMap (List<MerchantInfo> merchants)
        {
            if (merchants != null) {
            _clusterManager.ClearItems ();
                if (_map != null) {
                    var count = merchants.Count;

                    List<ClusterItem> items = new List<ClusterItem> ();

                    items = merchants.Where (item => item.Longitude.HasValue && item.Latitude.HasValue)
                        .Select (item => new ClusterItem (item.Latitude.Value, item.Longitude.Value, item.MerchantId)).ToList ();
                    _clusterManager.AddItems (items);
                }
                _clusterManager.Cluster ();
                _infoWindowAdapter = new InfoWindowAdapter (null, merchants, this.LayoutInflater);
                _map.SetInfoWindowAdapter (_infoWindowAdapter);
            }
        }
```

it works generally, but in some cases, I can't determine exactly when, I doesn't work, this line of code logs error :

```
_clusterManager.ClearItems ();
```

> [System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false [Timeline]
>   Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1bb9c140
>   time:774533321   at Kunicardus.Droid.MerchantsView.SetPointersOnMap
>   (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 merchants) [0x0000e] ....

Also there is another exception in some devices too:

> [monodroid-gc] GC cleanup summary: 104 objects tested - resurrecting
>   90. 
>   [Mono] GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 104 num_hash_entries 1603 sccs size 1347 init 0.00ms df1 5.25ms sort 0.28ms dfs2 3.81ms setup-cb
>   0.29ms free-data 2.71ms links 2418/2418/6240/12 dfs passes 4125/3765 [Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 13.89ms, total 14.29ms, bridge
>   83.17ms promoted 224K major 18128K los 11233K   at Kunicardus.Droid.MerchantsView.SetPointersOnMap
>   (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 merchants) [0x0000e]